# RabbitMQ channel best practice

Tags: java, tomcat, rabbitmq, channel, spring-rabbit

I am creating a REST api to send message to RabbitMQ and was trying to understand what are the best practice for creating/closing channels. I am using RabbitMQ Java client api.

Currently I have a class `RabbitMQPublisherConnection` where I spring inject RabbitMQ connection. This class is then spring injected to another class `RabbitMQPublisherChannel`. This class has the following function to create a channel:

> ```
> public class RabbitMQPublisherChannel {
>
> public Channel createChannel(String amqpExchange,
>                                          String exchangeType,
>                                          String queue,
>                                          String routingKey,
>                                          boolean durableExchange,
>                                          boolean durableQueue,
>                                          boolean autoDelete,
>                                          com.rabbitmq.client.Connection connection) throws IOException {
>         Channel channel = null;
>         channel = connection.createChannel();
>
>         if ((amqpExchange != null) && !"".equals(amqpExchange.trim())) {
>             if (log.isLoggable(Level.FINEST)) {
>                 log.finest("exchange:" + amqpExchange + ", type: " + exchangeType + ", durableExchange: " + durableExchange);
>             }
>             channel.exchangeDeclare(amqpExchange, exchangeType, durableExchange);
>             channel.queueDeclare(queue, durableQueue, false, autoDelete, null);
>             channel.queueBind(queue, amqpExchange, routingKey);
>         }
>         return channel;
>     } }
> ```

Now I have the third class `RabbitMQPublisher` where I spring inject `RabbitMQPublisherChannel` class. My application context looks like this:

```
<bean id="rabbitMQPublisher" class="com.rabbitmq.RabbitMQPublisher">
    <property name="publisherChannel"     ref="rabbitMQPublisherChannel"/>
</bean>

<bean id="rabbitMQPublisherChannel" class="com.rabbitmq.RabbitMQPublisherChannel">
    <property name="publisherConnection"     ref="rabbitMQPublisherConnection"/>
</bean>

<bean id="rabbitMQPublisherConnection" class="com.rabbitmq.RabbitMQPublisherConnection">
    <property name="rabbitMQConnectionSettingMap">
        .. connection ..
    </property>
</bean>
```

The class `RabbitMQPublisher` has the function to publish a message to RabbitMQ:

```
public boolean publishMessage(String message, String queueName){

    try {
        // Validate queue name
        com.rabbitmq.client.Channel channel     = publisherChannel.getRabbitMQChannel(queueName);
        RabbitMQConnection          settings    = publisherChannel.getPublisherConnection().getRabbitMQConnectionSettingMap().get(queueName);

        if (channel != null) {
            channel.basicPublish(settings.getAmqpExchange(), settings.getAmqpRoutingKey(), null, message.getBytes());
            publisherChannel.closeChannel(channel);
        }
    } catch (AlreadyClosedException e) {
        return FAILURE_RESPONSE;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return FAILURE_RESPONSE;
    }
    return SUCCESS_RESPONSE;
}
```

This application is run through tomcat and I noticed with AppDynamics that the closing the channel takes like 47% of the total time taken to publish message. When I remove the call to close the channel then I save this 47% of time which is like 32ms but then I notice in my RabbitMQ management console that the number of channel is ever increasing for that connection.

So my questions are -

1. Is this a good practice to open & close channel after every publish assuming that tomcat will get multiple requests per second?
2. Is this a good practice to have a channel pool shared among multiple threads (which [RabbitMQ recommends](http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#channel-threads) but also says `Even so, applications should prefer using a Channel per thread instead of sharing the same Channel across multiple threads.`) Does this mean create a new channel for every thread?
3. Will it be a good practice to not close channel and through RabbitMQ http api cleanup channels which are idle. (Please don't recommend this)?
4. Is it worth saving 32ms?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are a Spring Framework user, consider using [Spring AMQP](http://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/). The `RabbitTemplate` uses cached channels over a single connection with the channel being checked out of the cache (and returned) for each operation. The default cache size is 1, so it generally needs to be configured for an environment like yours.

Comment: Thanks @Gary! I used `spring-amqp` & it was really easy to use. It is very nicely structured as well. I just have few questions - How big is the community using/contributing to it? And How many people are already using it in production? I am very new to this so was worried if I will get enough help if I went live and there is a problem which I can't understand.

Comment: Welcome! The project is over 5 years old and is actively maintained as [you can see on github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/graphs/contributors). Myself and Artem Bilan are the main contributors these days (we are employed by Pivotal, as are most Spring Framework core contributors). Spring AMQP is therefore a first-class citizen in the Spring ecosystem and is the library of choice for Spring users. We do get occasional pull requests from the community (all are welcome!). You will find that Artem and myself are very responsive here. The rabbitmq team also work for Pivotal.

Comment: Thanks for the info Gary! Yes spring-amqp looks very neat and I am thinking of using it now. Do you have any IRC where I can post some simple questions or Stackoverflow is the only best way for it? Also are there any guideline for production deployment? Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is the question forum for Spring AMQP; use tag [spring-amqp] (but we monitor spring-rabbit too). Spring AMQP is just a java library so there's nothing to "deploy". You need to look at the rabbitmq documentation for broker configuration/deployment characteristics. For rabbitmq specific questions refer to the `rabbitmq-users` google group (but don't ask Spring-AMQP specific questions there).